# WordPress MultiSite Network Admin Redirect Loop After Adding www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302, wordpress

After learning that a naked WP domain will have 'cookieless subdomain' issues if a CDN is self hosted, I needed /  had to switch the root site on my **MultiSite** to www.

I followed [this guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-www-to-the-domains-of-a-multisite-network) by:

1. edit wp-config.php and change
   from
   define(‘DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘example.com’);
   to
   define(‘DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘www.example.com’);
2. get the search & replace script from https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB and read the instructions on the site on how to use it.

Everything worked as expected but for accessing the **Network Admin** Dashboard.

The dashboards to all the sites (*uses sub-domains, not folders*) and the permalink structure functions properly within the root site (www.example.com) and the sub-domain sites (subdomain.example.com). But, when I try to access the **Network Admin** (i.e. http://www.example.com/wp-admin/network/), I get a 302 redirect loop.

***Again, the Dashboards to all the sub-domain sites functions properly but not the Network Dashboard.***

I done some snooping on Google and here on SO but nothing has worked ( or fits to this situation ). I think this can be fixed in the .htacces but I am not verse in that so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Below is my configurations:

.htaccess:

```
. . .
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Disable trace and track
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Forbid Proxy comment posting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}%{HTTP:FORWARDED}%{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}%{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}%{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}%{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR}%{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-login.php|wp-admin/|wp-content/plugins/|wp-includes/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
. . .
```

...and in my config.php:

```
. . .
/* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
. . .
```

Comment: **If anyone knows the following is a bad idea, plz feel free to comment to why. Thnx!**

I commented line 18 within the .../wp-admin/network/admin.php:

    $redirect_network_admin_request = 0 !== strcasecmp( $current_blog->domain, $current_site->domain ) || 0 !== strcasecmp( $current_blog->path, $current_site->path );

Obviously I'll need to do this for each update :P  But until there is a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to:

> /wp-admin/network/admin.php

```
echo "current_blog domain: ".$current_blog->domain."<br>";
echo "current_site domain: ".$current_site->domain."<br>";
echo "current_blog path: ".$current_blog->path."<br>";
echo "current_site path: ".$current_site->path."<br>";
exit;
```

Check if the values are the same, this could be the problem.
Maybe you need to remove "www." at "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE"